# DOCTRINE2 oneToMany relationship with condition - no result

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

for example: 
I have entity Post ... Post have collection of entity Comment - relationship is oneToMany
Comments can be deleted by parameter deletedAt, which is default NULL
Comment have another collection of entity B - relationship is oneToMany

I made optimalization for querybuilder:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('post');
$qb->select('post, comments, objectsOfB')
    ->andWhere('post.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $postId)
    ->leftJoin('post.comments', 'comments')
    ->andWhere('comments.deletedAt is NULL')
    ->leftJoin('comments.objectsOfB', 'objectsOfB');
```

- this SQL works, if all comments are not deleted
- when all comments are deleted, then I have no result

how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `deletedAt` check to the join:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('post');
$qb->select('post, comments, objectsOfB')
    ->andWhere('post.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $postId)
    ->leftJoin('post.comments', 'comments', 'WITH', 'comments.deletedAt is NULL')
    ->leftJoin('comments.objectsOfB', 'objectsOfB');
```